# 'Totems of Hircine' quest markers not showing up

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

So, I picked up the *Totems of Hircine* quest from Aela, and the quest markers aren't there. I selected another quest to do, those markers showed up, so I did a few other quests thinking it would pop up and they haven't. I'd really like to get this quest done.

I am playing on the Xbox 360.

Answer (score 3):

> Journey to the location given by Aela and kill the enemies lurking
>   around. The location is radiant, and it can be any animal den, vampire
>   lair, or warlock lair with a boss chest. The totem is most often found
>   in a container in the furthest room from the entrance. Once you have
>   the totem, Aela will approach and ask if you have it. When you tell
>   her you do, she will tell you to bring it back to the Underforge. Once
>   you're in the Underforge, place it on the marked area and the quest
>   will finish. You can now pray to the totem to receive a new power
>   while in Beast Form, which replaces your old one.

[source](http://www.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Totems_of_Hircine)

Comment: Honestly, not even Northshore Landing is showing up

Comment: @GigaByte Northshore Landing is on Solstheim.  Enjoy the boat ride.  The quest marker should show up when you get there.